# r - Multiple boxplots of vector with breaks (and variable widths)

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a vector of numeric samples. I have calculated a smaller vector of breaks that group the values. I would like to create a boxplot that has one box for every interval, with the width of each box coming from a third vector, the same length as the breaks vector.

Here is some sample data. Please note that my real data has thousands of samples and at least tens of breaks:

```
v <- c(seq.int(5), seq.int(7) * 2, seq.int(4) * 3)
v1 <- c(1, 6, 13) # breaks
v2 <- c(5, 10, 2) # relative widths
```

This is how I might make separate boxplots, ignorant of the widths:

```
boxplot(v[v1[1]:v1[2]-1])
boxplot(v[v1[2]:v1[3]-1])
boxplot(v[v1[3]:length(v)])
```

I would like a solution that does a single boxplot() call without excessive data conditioning. For example, putting the vector in a data frame and adding a column for region/break number seems inelegant, but I'm not yet "thinking in R", so perhaps that is best.

Base R is preferred, but I will take what I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your question related to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184722/draw-frequency-density-histogram-in-r/23184895#23184895)?

Comment: That one is for barplot(). The boxplot() call would give me distribution information not available via barplot().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v1 <- c(v1, length(v) + 1)
a01 <- unlist(mapply(rep, 1:(length(v1)-1), diff(v1)))

boxplot(v ~ a01, names= paste0("g", 1:(length(v1)-1)))
```

Comment: This looks workable. Do you have a handy/clever way to generate the grouping vector from v1 in the original question?

Comment: Thanks. Much closer. I would like to replace the LETTERS[1:3] with something numeric to handle a larger v1.

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. I don't seem to have the reputation to mark this as an answer, but I consider it so.

Comment: Oops. It's not quite there. If there are more than 9 groups, the order gets scrambled (e.g. "g2" is after "g10").

Comment: How about: `a01 <- unlist(mapply(rep, factor(1:(length(v1)-1)), diff(v1)))` ?

Comment: You were right: I hadn't considered the alphabetical order. I edited now, have a look.

Comment: Yes, `factor()` was unnecessary. Works for me. Thank you!