# Frequency density histogram in Ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to draw up a histogram with varying bin width and no gaps between bins in ggplot. So exactly like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184722/draw-frequency-density-histogram-in-r), but in GGPLOT.

```
Class Width       Freq. Dist

0 <= x < 5          0.2 
5 <= x < 15         0.1
15 <= x < 20        1.2
20 <= x < 30        0.4
30 <= x < 40        0.4
```

So I want the X axis to go from 0-5,5-15,15-20,20-30 and 30-40 with the bars drawn appropriately.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688376/how-to-make-variable-bar-widths-in-ggplot2-not-overlap-or-gap. Is your data already summarized like that? What exactly does your raw input data look like. Di you have a vector of breaks or something?

Comment: Seems like it's pretty straitforward with `geom_rect`: `data.frame(left = c(0,5,15,20,30),right=c(5,15,20,30,40),freq=c(.2, .1, 1.2, .4, .4)) %>% ggplot() + geom_rect(aes(xmin=left, xmax=right, ymin=0, ymax=freq), color="black", fill=NA)`

Answer (score 0):

I will start with a recommendation of `ggplotify` package which enable easy translation of any base plot to ggplot format. This might be useful in many cases.

```r
breaks <- c(0, 5, 15, 20, 30, 40)
counts <- c(0.2, 0.1, 1.2, 0.4, 0.4)

gg <- ggplotify::as.ggplot(
~barplot(counts, diff(breaks),
  names = sprintf("[%g,%g)", breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1]),
  cex.names = 0.5,
  space = 0
))

class(gg)
#> [1] "gg"     "ggplot"

gg
```

[image]

To my answer I will add @MrFlick solution too, as it is only a comment. It is worth to show how good it works.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data.frame(left = c(0, 5, 15, 20, 30), 
                  right = c(5, 15, 20, 30, 40), 
                  freq = c(.2, .1, 1.2, .4, .4)) ) +
geom_rect(aes(xmin = left, xmax = right, ymin = 0, ymax = freq), 
          color = "black", 
          fill = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>